# django get primary key after saving modelform and pass it to the second form but second form can't be saved

Tags: django

I have a modelform that after saving the form i get the primary key and pass it to the second form but some how the second form data is not saved. I am not sure what i did wrong.

```
def create_new_survey(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewSurveyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_survey = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(add_question, args=(new_survey.pk,)))
           

    else:
        form = NewSurveyForm()
    return render(request, 'create_new_survey.html', {'form': form})


def add_question(request, survey_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        person = Survey.objects.get(id=survey_id)
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/choice')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        return render(request, 'question.html', {'form': form},)
```

**Models:**

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Questions(models.Model):
    survey = models.ForeignKey(Survey, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enter_question = models.CharField(max_length=900)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.enter_question
```

**Forms:**

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields = ('enter_question',)
```

Comment: Please add your forms to the question. Why do you pass the instance of _`Survey`_ to `QuestionForm`? `instance` is supposed to be the object the form is saving, considering the form is for `Questions` if you pass it an instance it should be an instance of `Questions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view `add_question` you define the form as `form = QuestionForm(request.POST, instance=person)`, but here `person` is an instance of `Survey` not of `Questions`. The `instance` keyword argument is used to *update* a specific instance not to specify foreign keys.

If you want to specify the foreign key you can simply modify the instance wrapped by the form or provide it an unsaved instance of `Questions`:

```py
def add_question(request, survey_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        person = Survey.objects.get(id=survey_id)
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST) # Remove instance from here
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.survey = person # Specify foreign key here
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/choice')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
        return render(request, 'question.html', {'form': form},)
```

> **Note:** Model names should ideally be singular in Django as normally Django automatically creates `verbose_name_plural` by adding an `s` to
> the model name so currently it ends up as `questionss` for you, so it
> should be `Question` instead of <s>`Questions`</s>.